# How to make application compatible to future versions of openssl?

Tags: c++, cmake, openssl, raspbian

In my c++ application I link to openssl like this:

```
add_library(SSL10 SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(SSL10 PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libssl.so.1.0.0")
```

This has worked fine so far - running the application on Raspbian.

Now I use the newest version of Raspbian (Raspbian stretch), where a newer version of openssl is included and my application complains because it needs libssl.so.1.0.0

How can I make my application use libssl.so.1.0.0 OR NEWER?

Or do I need to link to a static library like this:

```
add_library(SSL10 SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(SSL10 PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libssl.a")
```

Comment: There should be symbolic links like "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libssl.so" -> "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libssl.so.1.0.0" that are intended to avoid this issue.

Comment: I can not find a symbolic link on Raspbain Stretch called libssl.so. I am not sure if it was on Raspbian Jessie.

Comment: I would use a finder instead of a forced path. https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/module/FindOpenSSL.html